# A Corollary to Maschke's Theorem

Tags: representation-theory

I am reading *The Symmetric Group* by Sagan. Here is the corollary:

Let $G$ be a finite group and let $X$ be a matrix representation of $G$ of dimension $d>0$. Then there is a fixed matrix $T$ such that every matrix $X(g)$, where $g\in G$, has the form
\begin{equation*}
    TX(g){T}^{-1}=
    \begin{pmatrix}
        {X}^{(1)}(g) & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
        0 & {X}^{(2)}(g) & \cdots & 0 \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & \cdots & {X}^{(k)}(g)
    \end{pmatrix},
\end{equation*}
where each ${X}^{(i)}(g)$ is an irreducible matrix representation of $G$.

Can we find an expression of this fixed matrix $T$ and how to construct it?

Here is the picture of the corollary and its proof:

[image]

Comment: Could you answer this for $G=C_n$ cyclic?

Comment: I'm sorry. Can you give me a hint on what $T$ looks like for a cyclic group? I don't have any idea on this. Thank you so much for help!